# how to set the album art of a mp3 file in java

Tags: java, android

In My Java/Android Music Player,Need a feature to set/change album art in an music file,didint get any api/libraries till now,please help me to do this feature,thanks,i will appreciate all the valid answers [image: Like This Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're gonna need to use some API that lets you get music-related data. I can think of echonest: http://developer.echonest.com/ That lets you grab album art.